# ¿Cuándo y dónde se usa "darse por hacer algo" en lugar de "dar por hacer algo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, verbo-pronominal

Leía en [una publicación en Meta Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3504/83):

> De vez en cuando, cuando no tengo nada mejor que hacer, **se me da por revisar** respuesta y/o preguntas en las que participé y hacer un poco de limpieza.

Para mí, este *se me da por revisar* suena muy raro, habría escrito **me da por revisar**, sin pronominalizar el verbo *dar*. Sin embargo, consultado el autor, argentino, me [comentó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3504/edici%C3%B3n-de-preguntas-respuestas-antiguas-alg%C3%BAn-consenso-en-como-hacerlo?noredirect=1#comment12512_3504):

> el "me da por.." también se escucha, pero el "se me da por" es como más informal y común.

La [entrada del DPD sobre *dar*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=cucx2A8WkD6ImAtPsX) es muy extensa, pero apenas encuentro una referencia a reflexivo en la sección 9. dar(se) de sí, que no es el caso que aquí nos atañe. Lo mismo si buscamos referencias a su uso pronominal.

Mi pregunta pues es: ¿dónde es común este uso? ¿Es aceptable en un contexto escrito o solamente se utiliza en ambiente informal?

Comment: creo que el "se me da por revisar" es utilizado igual que el "se me ocurre"

Comment: @Mike creo que es diferente. "se me ocurre" es "tener una idea" y "me ocurre" es "me pasa/sucede".

Comment: Creo que debe ser regional. En Argentina se usa siempre la forma pronominal.

Comment: @DGaleano a lo que me refiero es que fue algo repentino o no planeado o tambien cuando es algo consistente o recurrente:  

se me da por hacer esto todos los lunes

Comment: Estoy pensando que quizá se haya hecho un paralelismo con otras formas: *se me ocurre..., se me antoja...*, etc. De todas formas no es lo que preguntas. Es difícil encontrar esta estructura porque siempre aparece mezclada con otros usos de "dar".

Comment: @pablodf76 dicho lo cual, ¿a ti como argentino te suena bien? Independientemente de si es correcto. Es que aquí en España se entiende, pero suena a incorrecto: nadie lo diría.

Comment: @fedorqui A mí me suena correcto. La forma no pronominal la encuentro bastante rara, no sé si diría que me suena a extranjera pero casi.

Comment: @pablodf76 qué bueno, qué curioso que a cada uno nos parezca raro lo del otro :) A ver si pasa por aquí Rodrigo y nos comenta cómo lo dicen en Chile. Le hago un ping a DGaleano, pues no me quedó claro sobre Colombia.

Comment: @DGaleano no me quedó claro: ¿en Colombia os suena bien así?

Comment: Bueno, no soy Rodrigo pero soy chileno, y a mi la forma pronominal me parece incorrecta y no creo haberla escuchado en Chile, sin embargo tengo la impresión, aunque no puedo asegurarlo, de que la he escuchado en España, en cuanto a la analogía que puede generar la pronominalización sólo se me ocurre "se me caen los pantalones", no logro explicarme el "se" en esta frase.

Comment: @AndrésChandía Es que normalmente se dice que algo "se cae". Si *mis* pantalones son los que se caen, entonces digo *me* porque los pantalones se *me* caen *a mí*.

Comment: @pablodf76 Si, eso lo entiendo, el "se" es algo impersonal que provoca la acción, el "me" esa acción provacada en mi. Pero en el caso del ejemplo no encuentro que haya algo externo provocando la acción, al contrario, interno, por ello veo que el "se" está demás, o más aún es inapropiado, por esto, y contestando a la pregunta creo que sólo es informal y además corresponde a localismos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo en lo personal diría simplemente "me da por", aunque "se me da por" no me choca al oído.

Un participante comentó:

> No logro explicarme el "se" en esta frase.

Yo me lo explico así: cuando a uno le da por usar esta frase, refiriéndose a la actividad X, muchas veces tiene la sensación de que X le entra en la mente por un proceso misterioso.  No se siente como fruto de análisis, lógica o planificación conciente.  Es como si el origen fuera ajeno a uno.  Y en general, las acciones con origen ajeno se expresan con verbos pronominales.

Ejemplos de la forma pronominal:

> A veces, se me da por sentir que la alegría es un delito de alta traición, y que soy culpable del privilegio de seguir vivo y libre. ― Eduardo Galeano, *Dias y noches de amor e de guerra* [fuente](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/670110-a-veces-se-me-da-por-sentir-que-la-alegr-a)
>
> Voy trenzando delgado un silbido,
>   luego un verso comienzo a tosar,
>   se me da por rasguear,
>   y me pongo a cantar
>   -- Duo Coplanacu, *La Llamadora* [fuente](http://www.cmtv.com.ar/discos_letras/letra.php?bnid=366&banda=Duo_Coplanacu&DS_DS=829&tmid=20738&tema=LA_LLAMADORA)
>
> Por eso, por eso que cuando fumo se me da por cavilar. -- José Larralde, *Herencia Pa' Un Hijo Gaucho (Parte II)* [fuente](https://www.letras.mus.br/jose-larralde/1690463/)

En un [foro](https://actacorporation.com/sintomas-de-la-depresion/) un participante usó las dos formas, en una sola frase:

> Cuando estoy caminando por la calle se me da por caminar con los ojos cerrados, o tambien cuando estoy en un centro comercial me da por dar pequeños gritos.